# I am making a chess game in python and I got this error. How do i fix it?

Tags: discord, discord.py, chess

This may seem like a dumb question at first, but nothing's been working so I need help.
In this code I have I am getting an error:

```
board_img = Image.open("ChessBoard.png")
start_x = 22
start_y = 1200
cell_size = 162
offset = cell_size//4

font = ImageFont.truetype("F25_font.ttf", 31)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(board_img)
```

The error is this:

```
File "main.py", line 281
font = ImageFont.truetype("F25_font.ttf", 31)
                                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: One more thing I want to say. Yes, all my indents are in place

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the file to determine the context, this error could mean that you have a mix of tabs and spaces somewhere within your code. Try convert all instances of tabs to spaces in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got some wierd indentation, maybe try this?

```
board_img = Image.open("ChessBoard.png")
start_x = 22
start_y = 1200
cell_size = 162
offset = cell_size//4

font = ImageFont.truetype("F25_font.ttf", 31)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(board_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused by mixing space and tab. I removed them all, it should work now using the code down there (you can fix the formating if you don't like it).

```
board_img=Image.Open("ChessBoard.png")
start_x=22
start_y=1200
cell_size=162
offset=cell_size//4

font=ImageFont.truetype("F25_font.ttf",31)
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(board_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

try opening all of the code up in IDLE and go to format then untabify regions. it might look like all the indents are correct, but there might be mixes of spaces and tabs.